# Remove duplicates and group by first column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a spreadsheet that I need:

1. To delete duplicates but leave them on the row they are initially on
   and
2. Delete the 2nd row based on what was deleted in the 1st row.

Since I just confused everyone (including myself), here is an example of what I need:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It appears your question and intended result are inconsistent. In your example, leaving the values in their initial position would result in 5 blank cells as opposed to the two you are displaying

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using Pivot Tables. They are very customizable to suit your needs with a little tinkering and easy to learn how to use.

Select your table and go to `Insert` > `Pivot Table` then select your output location.

Drag fields from the selection box into the four groups as you see below. I have added Value a second time in the Value location which will add a summary of the number of times each value appears, with subtotals rolling up through the Row Labels.

[image]